# How to pass data from expessjs middleware to a view ,

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Any idea , i want to add an express middleware to check for a cookie ( theme=dark ) and if exists adding the class … knowing that the middleware is in a separate file.
I know how to create the middleware but how to communicate between the middleware and the ejs view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views will look in a couple couple places for data.  One such place is `res.locals` (see doc [here](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.locals)).  So, since every middleware gets passed the `res` object, you can set some data in `res.locals` in the middleware and that will automatically be passed to the template.

For example:

```
app.use((res, req, next) => {
    res.locals.appName = "My App";
    next();
});
```

Then, you template could refer to the `appName` variable:

```
<%=appName%>
```

Otherwise, you could pass the data from your middleware to the actual route that renders the template by creating your own property on the `res` or `req` object and the route handler can grab the data from there and pass it as the data argument with `res.render(templateName, dataObj)`.

Comment: Thx for the clear easy answer.